# ecma2015 extend classes javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I want to do some extending in ecma2015 and i can't seem to understand how it works. I have written a method in plain JavaScript just like $.extend(), but i wanted to upgrade my code to classes.

Here is the following sample code that i tried.

```
var Test = ((window, document, undefined) => {
    class Defaults {
        constructor(options) {
            this.options = options || {};
            this.options.name = 'name';
            this.options.age = '23';
        }
    }

    class Test extends Defaults {
        constructor(selector, options) {
            super();
            this.selector = document.querySelector(selector);
            this.options = options;
        }

        createTest() {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            this.selector.appendChild(div);
        }

    }

    return Test; 
})(window, document);
```

And after i called it like this:

```
var test = new Test('#test', {
    name: 'nameInInstance'
});

test.createTest();

document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(test.options);
```

Now what i see is just the name from the instance.

Why isn't age passed to the child Class ? 
What am i missing ?

Comment: you need to call  `super(options)`, however you are overriding `options` with defaults. in child constructor you don't need to assign the options again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Test` constructor a) doesn't pass the options to the `super` call b) just overwrites the `.options` property with the argument, not caring for any defaults. You should be doing

```
class Test extends Defaults {
    constructor(selector, options) {
        super(options);
        this.selector = document.querySelector(selector);
    }
    …
```

That said, your `Defaults` class doesn't exactly use best practises either. It does mutate its arguments, which no constructor should do, and most importantly the defaults always override the passed-in options while you actually want it the other way round. You should manually copy them over:

```
class Defaults {
    constructor(options) {
        this.options = Object.assign({
            name: 'name',
            age: '23'
        }, options);
    }
}
```

And I would recommend not to use inheritance here at all, since `Defaults` is only used as a super class for `Test`, it should have been merged into it or have become a simple helper function; but let's assume you were only doing this for demonstration purposes.

Comment: so to gain access to the parent class constructor from inside child class you have to call super with the parameters from the parent constructor ? And if you not call super you can't have access to 'this' in the child constructor. I am a beginner at oop concepts (never actually used classless in any programming language) and i kinda find this confusing...

Comment: Yes, you have to call `super()` to make the parent constructor create and initialise the instance for you. If you don't do it, `this` is empty (that's a new ES6 concept). You should pass appropriate parameters to the parent constructor for that (depends on the context, but is usually some kind of pass-through).